# Declare an array of a generic struct specialized with different types

Tags: swift, generics

I know that Swift does not have *wildcard types* to specialize generic types. I have a problem I would know how to solve using them in a language like *Java*.

In the following example I'm trying to define a struct `Property` which encapsulates access to a property of a type `T` to perform two operations, getting the hash value of the value of that property on an instance of T and comparing the values of the property on two instances of `T`. To allow this, the struct contains a property `getter` holding a function which returns the value of the specific property on an instance. Because of this, the struct needs to be generic not only in `T` but also the type `E` of the property.

In the struct `Test`, I would like to define a static property `properties` holding an array of `Property` instances, one for each property of `Test`. I cannot see a way to do that because I don't know what type to use for `properties` or how to "hide" the type parameter `E` so that it does not need to be specified in the declaration of `properties`.

```
// Struct which represents a property of type T with a value of type E.
// Aside from initialization only T is visible from outside.
public struct Property<T, E: Hashable> {
    let getter: (T) -> E

    func getMemberHashValue(instance: T) -> Int {
        return getter(instance).hashValue
    }

    func equalsMembers(instance1: T, instance2: T) -> Bool {
        return getter(instance1) == getter(instance2)
    }
}

struct Test {
    // Some properties with different types
    let a: Int
    let b: Double

    // Array of Property instances for all properties of Test.
    // Not valid syntax.
    let properties: [Property<Test, ?>] = [
        Property(getter: { (instance: Test) in instance.a }),
        Property(getter: { (instance: Test) in instance.b })]
}
```

*I know that I could in this case substitute AnyHashable for the second type parameter in the declaration of `properties` as it has no associated types, but I would like to find a general solution I could apply in cases not involving `Hashable`.*

Is there a way to change this example to allow such a property `properties` to be defined holding multiple `Property` instances for properties of different types?

Comment: Could you explain what you would like to achieve. I think much of the question has your solution, would be best to clearly state what you want to achieve separately and then provide your attempt at solving it

Comment: @user1046037 The code is just an example exhibiting the issue because I'm not familiar enough with the terminology used by Swift for its generics features to explain it without an example. I'm looking for a replacement for _wildcard types_ from java to achieve the same effect (define an Array of a heterogeneously instantiated generic type). Maybe I will look at it tomorrow to make my question clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

## Overview:

- I am not sure I understood your question correctly.
- Might be worth stating why you would like a heterogeneous array, would lose all type safety in the process.
- Might be revisiting the design

## Option 1:

If it is absolutely required, if so just use an `NSArray` / `NSMutableArray`

## Option 2:

If you want to access properties of a `class` / `struct` / `enum` dynamically, you could do so with `KeyPath`.

### Code:

```
struct Test : Hashable {

    // Some properties with different types
    let a: Int
    let b: Double
    let c: String

    //This function will return any property of Test instance
    func property<T>(forKeyPath keyPath: KeyPath<Test, T>) -> T {

        return self[keyPath: keyPath]
    }

    //MARK: Hashable
    var hashValue: Int {
        return a.hashValue ^ b.hashValue ^ c.hashValue
    }

    //MARK: Equatable
    static func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {

        return lhs.a == rhs.a &&
            lhs.b == rhs.b &&
            lhs.c == rhs.c
    }
}

let test1 = Test(a: 10, b: 22.22, c: "aaaa")

let cValue      = test1.property(forKeyPath: \.c)           //aaaa
let cHashValue  = test1.property(forKeyPath: \.c.hashValue) //Hash value of aaaa

let someInt = 10 //This is also Hashable

var mixedArray = [AnyHashable]()

mixedArray.append(test1)
mixedArray.append(someInt)
```

### Refer:

If this matches your requirement, then please read about `KeyPath`, `PartialKeyPath`.

### Version:

Swift 4

Comment: Okay, I see. My question seems to be written very unclearly. Thanks for your answer anyways. My question was how to change my example to be able to define a property `properties` containing `Property` instances for all properties of the struct `Test`. In your answer, that property is missing.